# How to complete a "Runs Test" on daily returns data

Tags: r

I am a beginner using R-Studio for the first time.

I am trying to complete a "Runs Test" for daily closing returns of the s&p500.

I found the below code online, but when I try to use it with my data I am getting an error in the console.

Could anyone please tell me if they can see where I am going wrong or if I am missing a step.

The code I am trying to use is:

```
runs.test(x, exact = FALSE, alternative = c(“two.sided”, “less”, “greater”))
```

I have also attached an image of me trying to implement the code, my data is "rdailyprice".

Thank you.[image]

Comment: Please don't share data or code as photos, please share as plain text.

Comment: `alternative` should be one of those three options, e.g., `alternative = "two.sided"`

Comment: @jblood94 thanks for your response, I have edited the code to just "two.sided" but I am still receiving an error in the console - "Error in runs.test(rdailyprice, exact = FALSE, alternative = c("two.sided")) : could not find function "runs.test". Maybe this function is no longer available in R? Thanks.

Comment: Did you do `install.packages("snpar")` and then `library(snpar)`?